# Alert Error Mesage if user forcefully saving a record in dynamics crm 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I know to trigger execution a function from a traditional **save** of the dynamics crm 2013 form but I want to alert the error message from this **save** button which appears on to the grid of the duplication detection pop up.

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do, will you please describe what behavior you are expecting a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Customisation of the Duplicate Detection form isn't supported in CRM.

You could probably find the underlying form aspx file and edit that. However this would certainly not be supported and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you completely disable the save button

https://crmdynamite.wordpress.com/